# Basic I/O text replacing

Tags: java, io

I'm using the following program to read in a huge search engine database dump on search queries (>100 MB) and delete unneeded table data so that I'm left with just the keyword, so that I can mine the data for trends for one of my classes.

Here's what I have so far:

```
import java.io.*;
public class FileUtil {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        try {

            FileInputStream fStream = new FileInputStream("\\searches.txt");
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fStream));
            //PrintStream out = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream("searchesEdited.txt"));

            while (in.ready()) {
                System.out.println(in.readLine());
                String keyword = "foo"; // selected keyword to delete in txt file
                //search for string
                //delete the string
                //write newly edited file to searchesEdited.txt

            }
            in.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("File input error");
        }

    }
}
```

This works as expected and outputs all the data to the console, so I'm in the right direction. Now I just need to replace/delete the passed keyword. I have looked into the `replaceAll()` method but can't seem to get it implemented correctly. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: replaceAll method use regular expression (not string value). Check specs [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String, java.lang.String))

Answer (score 1):

Try,

```
String line=in.readLine();
 String keyword = "foo"; 
 String newLine=line.replaceAll(keyword,"");
```

Or

```
 String keyword ="\\bfoo\\b"; //word boundary match
 String newLine=line.replaceAll(keyword,"");
```

Comment: this seems to work, but after i compile and run it, the text i entered isnt saving and/or deleting the keywords. all i did was enter in your 3 lines above. ideas?

Comment: You need to create a file and write the result (newLine) in it.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use String.replace() with an empty String for the replacement, e.g.

```
 "search for a keyword and delete this keyword".replace("keyword", "")
```

returns

```
 "search for a  and delete this"
```

See also [here](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=42) for a simple tutorial on how to read and write text files.